# Google Custom Search not sending data to Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-custom-search

Google Custom Search data is not at all getting logged [after configuring Google Analytics Site Search](https://support.google.com/programmable-search/answer/2715510?hl=en). It has stopped logging after July 2021. Do we need to manually push the data to GA?